# Page Crashing and Lagging when page with 700 photos is opened

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I have a Generator which creates posts with photos (first code), and photos which are added(second code)). When I add about 250 < (more than 250) photos, it is lagging and loading about 10-15 seconds (on the phone version page is crashing). Because of that this website is without backend(static), I don't want to make a lot of pages manually. So What Can I do can anyone help me with that? Would "Lazy Loading" solve the problem?

```
const container = document.getElementById('accordion');
    
    apiResult.forEach((result, idx) => {
      // Create card element
      
      const card = document.createElement('div');
      card.classList = 'card-body';
    
      // Construct card content
      const content = `
      <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-img">
                      <img src="img/posters/Music/${result.title}.jpg" alt="post" />
                    </div>
                    <a href="#">
                      <h1 class="prodname">${result.title}</h1>
                      <h1 class="card-parametres">
                        ${result.description}
                      </h1>
                      <h1 class="price">
                        GEL
                        ${result.output}&#8382;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<a
                          href="more.html"
                          style="
                            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
                              270deg,
                              #c225ff 13.54%,
                              #2668ff 100%
                            );
                            background-clip: border-box;
                            -webkit-background-clip: text;
                            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; ;
                          "
                          >გაიგეთ მეტი</a
                        >
                      </h1>
                    </a>
                  </div>
      `;
    
      // Append newyly created card element to the container
      container.innerHTML += content;
    })
    </script>
```

```
  const apiResult = [

  {title:"12 Angry Man Poster №1",description: "ინფორმაცია",output: "ფასი"},
  {title:"12 Angry Man Poster №2",description: "ინფორმაცია",output: "ფასი"},
  {title:"1917 Poster",description: "ინფორმაცია",output: "ფასი"},
  {title:"Ace Ventura Poster №1",description: "ინფორმაცია",output: "ფასი"},
  {title:"Ace Ventura Poster №2",description: "ინფორმაცია",output: "ფასი"},
  {title:"Alien Poster №1",description: "ინფორმაცია",output: "ფასი"},
  {title:"Alien Poster №2",description: "ინფორმაცია",output: "ფასი"},
  {title:"Alien Poster №3",description: "ინფორმაცია",output: "ფასი"},
  {title:"Alien Poster №4",description: "ინფორმაცია",output: "ფასი"},
  {title:"Alien Poster №5",description: "ინფორმაცია",output: "ფასი"},
  {title:"Alien Poster №6",description: "ინფორმაცია",output: "ფასი"},
  {title:"Alien Poster №7",description: "ინფორმაცია",output: "ფასი"},
  {title:"Alien Poster №8",description: "ინფორმაცია",output: "ფასი"},
  {title:"Alien Poster №9",description: "ინფორმაცია",output: "ფასი"},
  {title:"Alien Poster №10",description: "ინფორმაცია",output: "ფასი"},
  {title:"Amelie Poster",description: "ინფორმაცია",output: "ფასი"},]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, lazy loading would definitely solve the problem.

Actually the easiest (although maybe not the best) solution might be just adding `loading="lazy"` attribute to your image tags.

More on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading)

Comment: It works on localhost,but when i hosted the website on github pages it needs the same time to load as it was without "lazy loading",also i inspected and recognised that github pages haven't added loading="lazy" to <img>,how can I correct it?!